# How can i connect a submit button to 2 inputs in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried using `onSubmit` on both the inputs and the submit button but I know that's wrong. and I've tried connecting the functions to the inputs. I've seen examples of people using https links to get it posted but I just want to be able to change the color and text when you click submit.

```
    this.state = {
      deftextcolor: "green",
      text: "Color Me"
    }
  }


colorchanger(newcolor) {
  this.setState({deftextcolor: newcolor})
}


textchanger(newtext) {
  this.setState({text: newtext})
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div className='colorer-wrapper'>
          <h1 style={{color: this.state.deftextcolor}}>{this.state.text}</h1>
          <input type="text"/>
          <input type="text"/>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could look into either wrap the input and button in a form-element and call a method onSubmit that manages your state or you could add onClick to your button or you could add onChange to your text inputs. Have a look here at some options you might have: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

here some example:

```js
const App =()=>{
const [state,setState] = React.useState({bgColor:"",textColor:"",color:"white",backgroundColor:"red"});

const handleChange = (e)=>{
const {target} = e
setState(current =>({...current,[target.name]:target.value}))
}
const onSubmit = (e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
if(state.bgColor.length>0 && state.textColor.length>0)
setState((current)=>({bgColor:"",textColor:"",color:current.textColor,backgroundColor:current.bgColor}))
}
return (<div><form style={{backgroundColor:state.backgroundColor,color:state.color}} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
<div>test style color</div>
<input type="text" name="bgColor" placeholder="background color" value={state.bgColor} onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" name="textColor" value={state.textColor} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="text color"/>
<button type="submit">Apply style </button>
</form></div>)
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
form{
width:100vw;
height:100vh
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

remenber you need to store event in variable because react update state asynchronously so the event will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Two places you can wire with `onSubmit`,

1. wire it with a button directly

```
<button onClick={onSubmit} />
```

2. wire it with form

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <button type="submit" />
</form>
```

Your function needs to look like

```
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
   // do something. here
  }
```

In your case, you also want to pass something into this function, so either calling `handleSubmit` directly or `<button onClick={ e=> { colorchanger(color) } />`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      deftextcolor: "green",
      text: "Color Me",
      defInput: '',
      textInput: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.id]: e.target.value})
  }


  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      deftextcolor: state.defInput,
      text: state.textInput,
      defInput: '',
      textInput: ''
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='colorer-wrapper'>
          <h1 style={{color: this.state.deftextcolor}}>{this.state.text}</h1>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.defInput} onChange={this.handleChange} id="defInput"/>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.textInput} onChange={this.handleChange} id="textInput"/>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App
```

You can attach the same method to both inputs to update state input values, and then another method to the button that uses state input values to update your other state properties.